# how to remove header from excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

experts, i want to remove a very first row from excel file using python. I am sharing a a screen print of my source excel file
[image]

i want out put as

[image]

I am using below python code to remove first row from excel but when i am reading it as data frame and printing that i am observing that data in data frame is being read as shown in below screen print

[image]

and the code which i am using is

```
import pandas as pd
import os
def remove_header():
 file_name = "AV Clients.xlsx"
 os.chmod(file_name, 0o777)
 df = pd.read_excel(file_name) #Read Excel file as a DataFrame
 #df = df.drop([0])
 print(df)
 #df.to_excel("AV_Clients1.xlsx", index=False)

remove_header()
```

Please suggest how i can remove a very first row from excel file whose screen print i have shared at top.
Thanks in advance
Kawaljeet

Comment: See `skiprows` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel(file_name, skiprows = 1)`

Comment: thanks @ALollz for document's link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add skiprows argument while reading excel.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
def remove_header():
    file_name = "AV Clients.xlsx"
    os.chmod(file_name, 0o777)
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name, skiprows = 1) #Read Excel file as a DataFrame
    print(df)
    df.to_excel("AV_Clients1.xlsx", index=False)
```

remove_header()